# How to escape slash angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to embed youtube iframe with `youtube ID` that is stored in database. But I got error in escaping slash may be.

```
 <tr ng-click="edit_source_data(source)" ng-repeat="source in sources">
        <td>{{source.title}}</td>
        <td>{{source.type}}</td>
        <td>
            <iframe width="100" height="100" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/{{source.link}}" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
            <!--https://www.youtube.com/embed/-->
        </td>
        <td><span class="delete" data-id="{{source.id}}" ng-click="del_source($event);
                $event.stopPropagation();">Delete</span></td>
    </tr>
```

But, if I remove `https://www.youtube.com/embed/` part from src then there is no error. How can I solve it. Thank you.

Comment: [`ng-src`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc)

Answer (score 1):

```
 <iframe width="100" height="100" 
  ng-src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/{{source.link}}" 
  frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>
 </iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to inject the $sce service in the controller and trustAsResourceUrl the url there.

In the controller:

```
function AppCtrl($scope, $sce) {
// ...
$scope.GetLink = function (source) {

  return  $sce.trustAsResourceUrl("https://www.youtube.com/embed/"+source.link);
 }
}
```

in the template

```
 <iframe width="100" height="100" 
ng-src="GetLink(source)"   frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: After trying your code. I got `The URI you submitted has disallowed characters` inside an iframe and cannot load video.

Comment: I woould get youtube ID from source.link. Value like `5VLPMeDuTs8` which is video id.